# Picking cards from deck

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

How many ways can I pick 2 cards from a deck where the first card is a spade and second is not a queen.

How can I solve this, and account for the queen of spades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate it into cases.  The first card can be the queen of spades-how many draws are possible?  The first draw can be a non-queen spade-how many of those are there and how many second cards are available?